# Distributing negative fraction across parentheses

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

At 13:26 in [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSId_Kgjzfg&index=55&list=PLg2tfDG3Ww4vrstKAZ0dajHx_hq85P0G) why/how did he:

> 1) Change the three negative fractions to positive ones
>
> 2) Change the denominator from 4 to 8 on the last fraction

I think it is because he did a half multiplied by everything inside the bracket which turned them from negative into positive, and changed the denominators?

Comment: I am not interested in clicking through to a video and trying to find the problem.  Please write up the question using MathJax per the FAQ.  Writing it up may inspire you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He had $y=\frac32-\frac12(-\frac14-\frac{3\sqrt{17}}4)$

He changes the negative fractions to positive ones by distributing the $-\frac12$ factor to each term in the parentheses; $4*2=8$ so the denominator of the fractions becomes $8$

Comment: Thanks. I thought so, that is what I tried to say in my paragraph under the question.